# Build .md vignette using devtools

Tags: r, package, knitr, devtools

I’m using `knitr::rmarkdown` (but `knitr::knitr` does the same) as my `VignetteEngine`. I then build my package vignette using `devtools::build_vignettes()`.

This works, but only creates HTML and R output files in `inst/doc`. What I *want* is a Markdown output file, since only that can be displayed directly within the Github project pages (for HTML files, Github shows the source and for Rmd files it shows a rendered output but — obviously — without executing the R blocks).

I’ve tried finding out how to specify the output for custom `VignetteEngine`s and I think that it should be possible (after all, other packages use this to build PDF vignettes, at a minimum) but I cannot find a way of doing this via `devtools::build_vignettes`. Is there no way around building the vignette manually (i.e. via `knitr::knit` or similar mechanisms that ignore the `VignetteBuilder` directives)?

I can’t find relevant information in the documentation/source either.

Comment: I wonder if adding `clean = FALSE` to [this line](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/blob/master/R/vignettes.r#L25) would help retain intermediate files...

Comment: @Roman Unfortunately it doesn’t seem to, at least I can’t get that to work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only output formats for vignettes are HTML and PDF (and LaTeX, but it is converted to PDF, not displayed).  Markdown isn't supported.

You can have arbitrary documentation files in your package (by convention you put them in inst/doc), but they aren't considered to be vignettes, so they won't be automatically built, functions like `browseVignettes()` will ignore them, etc.

To convert an Rmd file to md, just run `knitr::knit` on it.

Comment: That’s a shame but somewhat understandable. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  It may not be a vignette, but it's easy to produce the .md file.  (Actually, it could be a vignette too, just that R won't automatically produce the .md file.)

Comment: With larger vignettes, it’s a non-negligible, and completely unnecessary, overhead to process the `.rmd` source twice just to get at the Markdown intermediate (in my case, the vignette shows how to compile something with Rcpp. Making it is *slooooow*). In fact, even adding a Yaml frontmatter that specifies an output (`html_document`) with the option `keep_md` doesn’t keep the intermediate Markdown file. That’s just odd.