# Creating vignette from md file, not Rmd

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, r-package

Is there a way to create a package vignette from a Markdown (`.md`) file, as opposed to Rmarkdown (`.Rmd`) or any other type?

I found [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44356236/build-md-vignette-using-devtools) but it's about generating/keeping `.md` output from `.Rmd` input, whereas I want to start with `.md` input.

Comment: I understand that this question is more theoretical but still a piece of code would be nice or a little detail of what you've tried so far

Comment: @BobbyAxe For example, `devtools::install(build_vignettes=TRUE)` will produce nothing.

Comment: See if this [helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44356236/build-md-vignette-using-devtools)

Comment: Yes, that's the question I linked to, lol.

Comment: Didn't it worked just changing the extension from `.Rmd` to `.md`?

Comment: @TheRimalaya No; that's the point

Comment: It's a nice question, neat short and well written, downvoters should explain

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper as far as I can tell, the downvoters are people who don't actually know R, lol

Comment: I think they don't like short questions, they think it shows no effort, I've noticed this before. But short and clear questions are the best for users that will google their way here. They will not find this one as easily as they might have unfortunately, because of these downvotes.

Comment: @HongOoi why should that make a difference? A poorly laid out question with next to no effort shown by the OP is the same in any programming language and as such not suitably on-topic for [so].

Comment: Well if you don't have the baggage to understand the question you might want to think twice before assessing its quality and the effort of OP or lack thereof. I'm not sure how it is not obvious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## The Issue

The issue is that to use non-Sweave vignettes, you have to have a vignette engine. As [section 1.4.2 of the Writing R Extensions manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#Non_002dSweave-vignettes) explains

> Vignettes in formats other than Sweave are supported via “vignette engines”....
>
> R recognizes non-Sweave vignettes using filename extensions specified by the engine. For example, the knitr package supports the extension .Rmd (standing for “R markdown”). The user indicates the vignette engine within the vignette source using a \VignetteEngine line, for example
>
> %\VignetteEngine{knitr::knitr}
>
> This specifies the name of a package and an engine to use in place of Sweave in processing the vignette. As Sweave is the only engine supplied with the R distribution, the package providing any other engine must be specified in the ‘VignetteBuilder’ field of the package DESCRIPTION file, and also specified in the ‘Suggests’, ‘Imports’ or ‘Depends’ field (since its namespace must be available to build or check your package).
>
> ...
>
> Package writers who would like to supply vignette engines need to register those engines in the package .onLoad function. For example, that function could make the call
>
> tools::vignetteEngine("knitr", weave = vweave, tangle = vtangle,
>                         pattern = "[.]Rmd$", package = "knitr")

Unfortunately, none of `knitr`'s vignette engines (found [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/R/utils-vignettes.R)) use a pattern that will pickup pure `md` documents.

`R.rsp` provides a markdown vignette engine (see [here](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/R.rsp/blob/f6e64239516d776f6c79c2d9fb1af95faa221997/R/xweavetangle.R) and [here](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/R.rsp/blob/f6e64239516d776f6c79c2d9fb1af95faa221997/R/zzz.R)):

```
vignetteEngine("md", package=pkgname,
    pattern="[.]md$",
    weave=rspWeave,
    tangle=function(file, ..., pattern="[.]md$") asisTangle(file, ..., pattern=pattern)
)
```

which allows you to specify `R.rsp::md` as the vignette engine and use markdown vignettes. However, as discussed in the comments, there doesn't seem to be a way to allow for custom CSS stylesheets to change the default formatting.

## A Solution

So, I cooked up my own markdown vignette engine available in an R package called `mdVignettes` available [at this GitHub repo](https://github.com/duckmayr/mdVignettes).

To use it, simply add

```
Suggests: mdVignettes
VignetteBuilder: mdVignettes
```

to your `DESCRIPTION` file. Then, create a vignette that includes

```
%\VignetteEngine{mdVignettes::md}
```

You can include a custom CSS stylesheet by using

```
output:
    html_document:
        css: custom.css
```

instead of

```
output: html_document
```

in the YAML frontmatter (replacing `custom.css` with your stylesheet's filename).

As an example, I created a dummy R package via

```
devtools::create("vigex", rstudio = FALSE)
```

Then I added the Suggests and VignetteBuilder lines above to the DESCRIPTION, created a `vignettes/` directory, and added the following in `vigex.md`:

```
---
title: "A Simple Vignette"
author: "duckmayr"
output:
    html_document:
        css: custom.css
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{vigex}
  %\VignetteEngine{mdVignettes::md}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---

# A simple vignette

Here's an example of custom-formatted code:

    print("Hello, world!")
```

and the following in `vignettes/custom.css`:

```
code {
    background: wheat;
    color: green;
}
```

Then I installed the package with the vignette via

```
devtools::install("vigex", build_vignettes = TRUE)
```

And `vignette("vigex")` displayed the following:

[image: vignette example]

## An alternate solution: using R.rsp

First, add

```
Suggests: R.rsp
VignetteBuilder: R.rsp
```

to your `DESCRIPTION` file. Then, create a vignette that includes

```
%\VignetteEngine{R.rsp::md}
```

It's that simple. I did this using

```
package.skeleton("vignetteEX")
```

from R, adding the `DESCRIPTION` lines above, then saving the following in `vignettes/vignetteEX.md`:

```
---
title: "Vignette Example"
author: "duckmayr"
date: "October 26, 2018"
output: html_document
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{vignetteEX}
  %\VignetteEngine{R.rsp::md}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---

# A simple vignette

Here it is.
```

Then I built and installed the package (via `R CMD build` and `R CMD INSTALL`) and was able to open the vignette via

```
vignette("vignetteEX")
```

Comment: Nice (+1), although I was hoping to find a solution that didn't involve installing more dependencies....

Comment: Actually, after looking at the dependencies for knitr, this is quite lightweight

Comment: Also, would you know how to change the default formatting for each style? In particular, I'd like to change `code` to be in Consolas, not Lucida Console, and remove the borders.

Comment: @HongOoi When I first saw your comment I thought it should be simple to include custom css, but as it turns out that doesn't work as I'd expect. I'll see if I can find a workaround.

Comment: I found where that formatting information is stored. It's in the markdown package, which R.rsp uses to process .md files. https://github.com/rstudio/markdown/blob/5abbfaec56cabf1b59ee5d72640d83b30dd71172/inst/resources/markdown.css#L15 
Would still like to know if/how you can include css formatting in a .md vignette though.

Comment: @HongOoi As far as I can tell, `R.rsp` won't include custom css, and I haven't seen any other `md` vignette engines around. I toyed around a little with creating a more flexible `md` engine; I'll post on that if I have time to get it useful.

Comment: @HongOoi I've added a custom vignette engine solution that will allow you to specify a different CSS stylesheet; see the updated answer.

Comment: Very nice! You might want to think about putting this on CRAN; there'll probably be a few people who could use this ever since _somebody_ persuaded GitHub to stop rendering Rmd files....

Answer (score 6):

A simpler solution is simply to include the original markdown in an Rmarkdown stub.

your.md contains:

```
# R Markdown

lorem ipsum
```

Then vignette.Rmd contains:

````
---
title: "Vignette Title"
author: "Vignette Author"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: rmarkdown::html_vignette:
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{Vignette Title}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---

```{r child = "your.md"}
```
````

This way, you can write in pure markdown, and just use the Rmd stubs so that the vignettes are built. Is that what you wanted?